# Why does assigning to a class attribute with the same name as a local variable raise a NameError?

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

Consider this class definition:

```
def func():
    x = 5

    class Foo:
        x = x

func()
```

I expected this to create a class with an attribute `x` set to 5 - but instead, it throws a NameError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 7, in <module>
    func()
  File "untitled.py", line 4, in func
    class Foo:
  File "untitled.py", line 5, in Foo
    x = x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

However, that error is only raised inside of a function, and only if `x` is a local variable. All of these snippets work just fine:

```
x = 5

class Foo:
    x = x
```

```
x = 5

def func():
    class Foo:
        x = x

func()
```

```
class Bar:
    x = 5

    class Foo:
        x = x
```

```
def func():
    x = 5

    class Foo:
        y = x

func()
```

What's causing this strange behavior?

Comment: looks like a global vs nonlocal issue

Comment: For the behaviour you want, just set `Foo.x = x` *after* the class definition.

Comment: [This issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue9226) seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Python compiler looks at all the l-values in a code block when determining which variables are local. Since in your problematic code, `x` is used as an l-value in the `class` block, it is regarded as a variable local to the `class` block, and as such, it is considered to be referenced before it is assigned a value, and hence the exception.

Comment: So this is a CPython issue, then? Would you say it's a bug?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug. It's just by design that the scope of each variable is fixed for any given code block, so that the variable `x` in a code block with `x = x` doesn't have to transition from a parent-scoped variable to a local variable at run time. I agree that it's somewhat counter-intuitive, but it's likely better for efficiency's sake.